# $(v,t)$ Diagram with deceleration and braking

Tags: kinematics, acceleration

How do you make a $(v,t)$ diagram with braking and deceleration?

> *When someone for instance brakes and then stops with an uniform acceleration?*

Answer (score 1):

Uniform acceleration means an even, or **linear**, change in speed $v$. A linear function is a straight line.

So, just draw a straight line. The angle of that straight line depends on the value of $a$; the larger a value, the steeper. You can simply count it out:

- For each unit (each second) out horizontally, you must go up/down the whole value of $a$.
- And there you make a dot.
- Then go one more time-unit out and go the value $a$ up, and make another dot.
- Continue until you have many dots.

These dots will all lie on straight line.